# pandas read_table with stopping strings to delimit different dataframes to assign

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file of the form :

```
LINE 1 to SKIP
LINE 2 to SKIP
2.13999987 0.139999986 -0.398405492 1
2.61999989 6.0000062E-2 0.450082362 1
2.74000001 5.99999428E-2 1.04403841 1
2.84000015 4.00000811E-2 6.17375337E-2 1
IGN IGN IGN IGN 
21.4200001 0.420000076 1.53572667 1
22.3199997 0.479999542 -0.595370948 1
23.3199997 0.520000458 0.136062101 1
24.3600006 0.519999504 -0.520044923 1
25.3999996 0.520000458 2.45230961 1
26.4399986 0.519999504 -2.08248448 1
27.4799995 0.520000458 -0.263438225 1
IGN IGN IGN IGN 
58.6800003 0.520000458 -0.789233088 1
59.7200012 0.520000458 -1.02961564 1
60.7600021 0.51999855 -0.889572859 1
61.7999992 0.520000458 -1.03346229 1
62.8400002 0.520000458 4.94940579E-2 1
```

And I would like to read that with pandas like:

```
df_first = pd.read_table('file.txt', names=names, delimiter=' ', skiprows=3, nrows=4)
```

(where `names` are the name of each column in the file.txt).
I want to assign each series of rows to a `df` with a given name specified (perhaps with an array of names), until the `IGN IGN IGN IGN` string is met, and then assign the rest of the rows to the following `df` again until the the next `IGN IGN IGN IGN` string is met, till the end of the file.

What is a good way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I was confronted by this problem couple of years ago. My solution:

```
names =['1','2', '3', '4']
df = pd.read_table('file.txt', names=names, delimiter=' ', skiprows=3) # Read the data
index = list(df.loc[df['1']=='IGN'].index) # Getting the index, where IGN ocures
df_list = [] # Defining the dataframe-List ot store the dataframes
start = df.index.min() # Defining the start index
for end in index: # looping through all indeces
    df_list.append(df.loc[start:end-1])
    start = end+1
else:
    df_list.append(df.loc[start:]) # Getting the last slice of the main dataframe
```

You can call the single dataframes like this:

```
df_list[0]
df_list[1]
...
df_list[n]
```

Greetings

Comment: Is there a simple way to call the resulting dfs as `df_var1`, `df_var2`, `df_anothervar1`, `df_anothervar2`, taking the names, for example, from a list of var_names?

Comment: Also, the values returned this way are string and not floats? I'd need the floats

Comment: Why do you need the data in separate variables? About the data type, you can add a row to change the data type `df[colname].astype(float)`

Comment: cause each subset comes from different data sources and I would like to give them meaningful representative names

Comment: If you know, how many sets you would have, than you define the meaningful variables. But if you don't, than you can enumerate the loop and append the current increment to a new array, so you would know the sources of the set